# How do I defeat Xiatol when playing as a wizard?

Tags: cardinal-quest-2

There is plenty of time for the dragon to roast me between fireballs, especially on maps that offer little cover. My attack stat is never good enough to get in a hit with a weapon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving your speed gives your more turns per ingame second. Improving your intellect gives your fewer turns for your cooldown.   Generally, Intellect, then Speed are the stats you want on a Wizard.

After that, about all you can do is charm minons, create mirrors, chug potions, whatever you have - but above all, keep kiting him.

Comment: Xiatol is a lady, as in the Hall of the Mountain Queen achievement and when the Wizard refers to her as the "brood mother."